# How to do Gtk TextIter arithmetic

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am attempting to use Gtk TextIter objects to lift three-character slices out of a TextBuffer, but am having trouble with the arithmetic. I set up an iterator p to point to the start of the range and want q to point to three characters further on.

I have tried...

```
q = p + 3;              // Doesn't compile
q = p; q += 3;          // Doesn't compile
q = p; q++; q++; q++;   // Happy
```

I'd like to know what the correct way to do this is. The third method works, but looks like a ghastly hack.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/2.19/classGtk_1_1TextIter.html) you'll see that `TextIter` doesn't have a `+` or `+=` operator. It's a bidirectional iterator and not a random access iterator so this is as it should be.

You can use either:

```
q = p;
std::advance(q, 3);
```

or

```
q = p;
q.forward_chars(3);
```

Comment: Thank you, Staffan and unwind.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.

The underlying C API has `gtk_text_iter_forward_chars()` which should do the right thing.  Maybe read the source, and/or file a bug on the C++ wrapper?

Comment: FWIW, I'm using Gtk 2.20, g++ 4.4.3 and Ubuntu 10.4. I'm glad to hear this isn't quite what you'd expect; I was worried I'd lost the plot entirely.